# Heroku - what change in code to use postgresql instead mysql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, hibernate, maven, heroku

I prepared website in Spring/Maven with use of MySQL db, Tomcat. I decided to use Heroku free account, because I have domain, db and Java in one place. Problem is that Heroku uses postgresql for free but mysql is payable. I would like to ask you help and explanation clearly what I should change in my application's code(pom.xml, hibernate.properties etc) to use postgresql instead of mysql. Below I show files I think should be changed. Do I have to add any new files? I beg your indulgence.

```
***POM.XML***

jdbc.driver.class.name      =com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url                    =jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_users?useSSL=false&characterEncoding=UTF-8
jdbc.user.name              =root
jdbc.password               =root

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto      =update
hibernate.show_sql          =true
hibernate.format_sql        =true
hibernate.generate_statistics=false


***HibernateConfig.java***

 @Configuration
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:hibernate.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.website.dao")
public class HibernateConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

// 1. create DataSource

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driver.class.name"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.user.name"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));

    return dataSource;
}

// 2. EntityManagerFactory

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", environment.getProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics"));

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.website.model");
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Comment: I think you have correctly answered your own question.  I recommend that you try editing the files you outline above, and if there's anything else you need to do, add that information as an answer to this question.  This does look right to me.

Comment: Great! Actually the question is what should I change, what should I write and what remove from the code?